# SQL How to Pivot on repeating date ranges Grouped By ID

Tags: sql

I need help pivoting data from a table. 
I have a Vacation Request table

```
CREATE TABLE EmpVacRequest
(EmpID int, VacReqPri int , StartDate date, EndDate date)
```

I seed it with sample data

```
INSERT INTO EmpVacRequest 
(EmpID,VacReqPri,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (100,1,'2016-1-1','2016-1-3')

INSERT INTO EmpVacRequest 
(EmpID,VacReqPri,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (100,2,'2016-2-4','2016-2-8')

INSERT INTO EmpVacRequest 
(EmpID,VacReqPri,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (200,1,'2016-1-2','2016-1-5')

INSERT INTO EmpVacRequest 
(EmpID,VacReqPri,StartDate,EndDate) VALUES (200,2,'2016-2-1','2016-2-3')
```

The output I need would look like something like this:

```
EmpId       Vac1Start      Vac1End     Vac2Start   Vac2End
100         2016-1-1       2016-1-3    2016-2-4    2016-2-8
200         2016-1-2       2016-1-5    2016-2-1    2016-2-3
```

Each employee gets only 4 vacation requests prioritized 1 - 4 so I thought maybe I would create a new table with hard coded columns and populate it using a Cursor or CTE but I'm hoping someone might have a more elegant solution.

I have a [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a7176) if it helps provide a solution.

Comment: how many distinct values does the `vacreqpri` column have? is it fixed?

Comment: @vkp There will be 4 distinct `vacreqpri` 1,2,3,4. The concept is that each employee gets four ranges of vacation they want for the upcoming year and prioritize them 1 through 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query for 2 . You can easily extend it for 4.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a7176/29)

```
WITH EMPVACREQUESTCTE AS
(
SELECT VACREQPRI AS RN,* FROM EMPVACREQUEST
)

SELECT T1.EMPID,MAX(STARTDATE1) AS VAC1START,MAX(ENDDATE1) AS VAC1END,MAX(STARTDATE2) AS VAC2START,MAX(ENDDATE2) AS VAC1END FROM
(
    SELECT RN,EMPID,MAX([1]) STARTDATE1,MAX([2]) STARTDATE2 FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM EMPVACREQUESTCTE
        PIVOT
        (MAX(STARTDATE) FOR VACREQPRI IN ([1],[2])) P
    ) K
    GROUP BY EMPID,RN
)T1 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT RN,EMPID,MAX([1]) ENDDATE1,MAX([2]) ENDDATE2 FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM EMPVACREQUESTCTE
        PIVOT
        (MAX(ENDDATE) FOR VACREQPRI IN ([1],[2])) P
    ) K
    GROUP BY EMPID,RN
)T2 
   ON T1.EMPID = T2.EMPID AND T1.RN = T2.RN
GROUP BY T1.EMPID
```

Comment: Awesome study in pivot use. I'll be able to reuse this code for other projects. Great work!

Answer (score 1):

As @Dark Knight already added his solution I thought I would add one more,

You could also try:

```
select 
      empid, 
      max(case  when VacReqPri = 1 then startdate end) as vac1start,
      max(case  when VacReqPri = 1 then enddate end) as vac1end,
      max(case  when VacReqPri = 2 then startdate end) as vac2start,
      max(case  when VacReqPri = 2 then enddate end) as vac2end
from EmpVacRequest group by empid
```

Comment: Both answers work but yours seems easier to read and extend as a cte. Thanks.